# Failed to install valet-windows

Tags: php, windows, laravel, valet

PS C:\Windows\system32> composer global require cretueusebiu/valet-windows

Changed current directory to C:/Users/user/AppData/Roaming/Composer
Using version ^2.1 for cretueusebiu/valet-windows
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

**Problem 1**

- Conclusion: don't install cretueusebiu/valet-windows 2.1.1
- Conclusion: remove illuminate/container v6.10.0
- Installation request for cretueusebiu/valet-windows ^2.1 -> satisfiable by cretueusebiu/valet-windows[2.1.0, 2.1.1].
- Conclusion: don't install illuminate/container v6.10.0

  cretueusebiu/valet-windows 2.1.0 requires illuminate/container ~5.1 -> satisfiable by illuminate/container[5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9].

```
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[5.7.18, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[5.7.19, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.1.1, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.1.13, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.1.16, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.1.2, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.1.20, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.1.22, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.1.25, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.1.28, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.1.30, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.1.31, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.1.41, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.1.6, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.1.8, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.2.0, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.2.19, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.2.21, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.2.24, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.2.25, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.2.26, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.2.27, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.2.28, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.2.31, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.2.32, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.2.37, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.2.43, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.2.45, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.2.6, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.2.7, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.3.0, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.3.16, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.3.23, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.3.4, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.4.0, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.4.13, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.4.17, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.4.19, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.4.27, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.4.36, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.4.9, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.5.0, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.5.16, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.5.17, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.5.2, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.5.28, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.5.33, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.5.34, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.5.35, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.5.36, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.5.37, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.5.39, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.5.40, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.5.41, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.5.43, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.5.44, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.0, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.1, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.10, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.11, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.12, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.13, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.14, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.15, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.16, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.17, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.19, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.2, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.20, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.21, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.22, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.23, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.24, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.25, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.26, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.27, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.28, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.29, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.3, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.30, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.31, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.32, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.33, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.34, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.35, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.36, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.37, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.38, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.39, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.4, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.5, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.6, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.7, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.8, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.6.9, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.7.0, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.7.1, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.7.10, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.7.11, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.7.15, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.7.2, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.7.20, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.7.21, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.7.22, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.7.23, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.7.26, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.7.27, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.7.28, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.7.3, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.7.4, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.7.5, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.7.6, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.7.7, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.7.8, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.7.9, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.8.0, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.8.11, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.8.12, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.8.14, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.8.15, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.8.17, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.8.18, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.8.19, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.8.2, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.8.20, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.8.22, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.8.24, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.8.27, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.8.28, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.8.29, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.8.3, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.8.30, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.8.31, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.8.32, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.8.33, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.8.34, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.8.35, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.8.36, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.8.4, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.8.8, v6.10.0].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v5.8.9, v6.10.0].
    - Installation request for illuminate/container (locked at v6.10.0) -> satisfiable by illuminate/container[v6.10.0].
```

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

Answer (score 0):

**cretueusebiu/valet-windows** requires illuminate/container ~5.1, but the version of illuminate/container in your system is higher (6.10.0) which makes composer thinks that its not supported for some reason.

I used version alias as a workaround:

```
"illuminate/container": "7.14.1 as 5.7.17" --format: [current exact version] as [alias version]--
```

which makes composer regconise it as the lower version when installing cretueusebiu/valet-windows.